# Openssl errors in PowerShell when converting certificates

Tags: powershell, openssl, certificate, pem

I am currently working on converting CER to PEM.

I am working on building a script to convert multiple certs into a different format using Openssl. I am running PowerShell 7 and Openssl 1.1.1e. When I run my script, I get some Openssl errors, **however it does still seem to convert the certificate as I still get a .pem file afterwards**. Below are the errors:

```
Can't open Folder\Path for reading, Permission denied
17956:error:02001005:system library:fopen:Input/output error:..\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:69:fopen('C:\Users\localadmin\Desktop\PowerShell\Testing Environment\Folder\Path','r')
17956:error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib:..\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:78:
unable to load certificate
Can't open Folder\Path for reading, Permission denied
19560:error:02001005:system library:fopen:Input/output error:..\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:69:fopen('C:\Users\localadmin\Desktop\PowerShell\Testing Environment\Folder\Path','r')
19560:error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib:..\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:78:
unable to load certificate
unable to load certificate
17960:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:..\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
unable to load certificate
16568:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:..\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
unable to load certificate
21500:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:..\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
unable to load certificate
15500:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:..\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

I don't have any errors using Openssl to make the CSR or private key. Below is the code I'm using for the conversion:

```
if($CertType -eq "PEM") {
    Get-ChildItem $ScriptPath\$Kit -Recurse -Force | ForEach-Object {
        $OutFile = $_.FullName.ToString().Replace(".cer",".pem")
        openssl x509 -in $_.FullName -outform PEM -out "$Outfile"}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to figure it out. In my code for converting the CER file to PEM, When recursing through my folders I added the line to include only the CER files and not the Key files in there as well. Below is the edited code.

```
if($CertType -eq "PEM") {
    Get-ChildItem $ScriptPath\$Kit -Recurse -include "*.cer" | ForEach-Object {
        $OutFile = $_.FullName.ToString().Replace(".cer",".pem")
        openssl x509 -in $_.FullName -outform PEM -out "$Outfile"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default openssl [x509](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/x509.html) command format is pem, so your command line is converting from pem to pem.
So the errors are that openssl does not understand the file format, as it's expecting a pem formatted file.

I assume you want to convert DER format to PEM format.
So what you want to do is:

openssl x509 -in {infilename} -inform der -out {outfilename}

That will expect a DER formatted file on input and output as a PEM formatted file.

or you can explicitly specify both sides like:

openssl x509 -in {infilename} -inform der -out {outfilename} -outform pem

From the manual:

> -inform DER|PEM
>
> This specifies the input format normally the command will expect an
>   X509 certificate but this can change if other options such as -req are
>   present. The DER format is the DER encoding of the certificate and PEM
>   is the base64 encoding of the DER encoding with header and footer
>   lines added. The default format is PEM.
>
> -outform DER|PEM
>
> This specifies the output format, the options have the same meaning
>   and default as the -inform option.

Comment: I am attempting to convert a .cer to a .pem. Later in the script I will have to option to convert to DER. I am using this website as my basis for the openssl command strings. https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO26449.html. I've done this before, and I don't recall seeing the same errors, but I could be mistaken

Comment: The conversation to DER format is incorrect in that link, maybe it was valid for older openssl versions(?) but it's not the case now.

Comment: In you want to explicit you can specify both the inform and outform to be sure it does what you want.  e.g. openssl x509 -in {infile} -inform der -out {outfile} -outform pem